# Maximise Sharpe ratio subject to contraints in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I want to maximize the value of q[1](Sharpe Ratio), subject to following constraints in julia.

1. Value elements of W is positive. ( W[i] >0 )
2. Sum of values of W is 1. ( sum(W[1:5]) == 1 )

   ```
   function getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S)
     q = ( W'*ex_mu ) / sqrt((W'*S*W))
     return q[1]
   end
   ```

For Reference :: W is (5X1) vector,ex_mu is (5x1) vector and S is (5x5) matrix.
I found out two julia libraries to use JuMP and Optim.jl , but not able to translate the function getSharpeRatio as required by the libraries.

**Update** : I have done so far but seems like transpose is not implemented yet in JuMP library
using JuMP

```
function getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S)
   return dot(W', ex_mu) / sqrt(dot(W',S*W))
end

items  = [1;2;3;4;5]
m = Model()
@variable(m, 0 <= W[items] <= 1)
@constraint(m, sum{ W[item] , item in items} == 1)
@objective(m, Max, getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S))
solve(m)
println(getvalue(W))
```

Any suggestions how to go about this.

Comment: Just a quick tip, use q = dot(W, ex_mu) / sqrt(dot(W, S*W)) instead, if you want a scalar. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did this in Julia using `NLopt` a year or so ago. Unfortunately the code is not able to be open-sourced at this time but if you have a go with `NLopt` and run into a problem I can answer any *specific* question you might have. Also, you don't *have* to solve this problem using numerical optimisation. See, e.g. Irlicht (2014) "Fast Recursive Portfolio Optimization"

Comment: So as pointed out by @pkofod I have updated my getSharpeRatio function as follows :                                                                 function getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S)
   return dot(W', ex_mu) / sqrt(dot(W, S*W))
end                                                                                                          Now i intend to add the two constraints and maximize the calculated sharpe ratio. so how should i define that using NLopt/JuMP/Optim.jl

Comment: using JuMP

function getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S)
  return dot(W', ex_mu) / sqrt(dot(W',S*W))
end

items  = [1;2;3;4;5]
m = Model()
@variable(m, 0 <= W[items] <= 1)
shapreratio = getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S)
@objective(m, Max, getSharpeRatio(W,ex_mu,S))
@constraint(m, sum{ W[item] , item in items} == 1)
solve(m)
println(getvalue(W))

Answer (score 0):

I believe your function needs to be on one array. Make a 25+5+5 length vector, and make `getSharpeRatio(v)` start  `W,ex_mu,S=translate(v)` function which gets your temporary arrays out using views.

```
translate(v) = (view(v,1:5),view(v,6:10),reshape(view(11:35),5,5))
```

That won't allocate, but it means your new function can be

```
function getSharpeRatio(v)
  W,ex_mu,S=translate(v)
  dot(W,ex_mu)/ sqrt(dot(W,S*W))
end
```

which matches what JuMP/Optim expect. From there, you need to re-do your constraints to match the indices from here... though I think I set this up (with W first) so that way it'll work.