# Adding constraints to a function using Optim.jl in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I am using Optim.jl Library to maximise the Sharpe Ratio value

```
using Optim
function getSharpeRatioNegative(W,ex_mu,S)
  return  dot(W', ex_mu) / sqrt(dot(W',S*W))  
end
f(W::Vector) = getSharpeRatioNegative(W,ex_mu,S) 
result = optimize(f, [0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2])
```

How can I add the following constraints:

1. Value elements of W is positive. ( W[i] >0 )
2. Sum of values of W is 1. ( sum(W[1:5]) == 1 )

Comment: Optim.jl doesn't currently do constrained optimization. Check out [JuMP](https://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that.

Comment: can you help me out with the transpose problem in JuMP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159761/maximise-sharpe-ratio-subject-to-contraints-in-julia

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas  you should expand that into an answer.

Comment: If you provide `S` and `ex_mu` I can show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Optim.jl doesn't currently do constrained optimization. [There is a PR to add this, but it's not merged quite yet](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl/pull/303). Check out [JuMP](https://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for doing constrained optimization.